# Entity Framework Navigation property not working

Tags: c#, ado.net, entity-framework-6, navigation-properties

I have a many to many relationship like below.

- Company[CompanyID, Name] - nav prop SalaryTabs
- SalaryTab[ID,Salary, Since, CompanyId, Employeeid] - nav prop
  (Company, Employee), and
- Employee[EmployeeID,FirstName, LastName, DOB] -nav prop
  (SalaryTabs)

But When I try to use Linq to query the tables using the navigation property. It wont just show up in the intellisence at all.

For example, I want to access `contxt.SalaryTabs.Company.xxx` The navigation property Company will not load the xxx and will not show up in the intellisence and if I manually type it. I get some errors.

If I try to do something like

```
//Delete an employee (identified via id) from a specific company(identified via id)

public bool DeleteEmployeeFromSpecificCompany(Guid employeeID, Guid companyID)
{
    try
    {
        var emp = dbContext.Employees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeID == employeeID);
        dbContext.Companies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CompanyID == companyID).SalaryTabs.Employee.Remove(emp);

        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The navigation property doesn't work. I can't access context.Companies.SalaryTab.xxxx for example. I have been having this problem since yester which I didn't have before. I could navigate from one entity to another using the navigation properties but now it won't load and offer the options anymore.

I appreciate any input.

Comment: Do you have LazyLoading enabled?

Comment: Yes I do. It's enabled. This issue began yesterday but the day before I could navigate without any issues, but now I can't. I used the Modelfirst approach to create the DB using ADO.NET EF

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<ModelFirstExamSolution.Model.SalaryTab>' does not contain a definition for 'Employee' and no extension method 'Employee' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<ModelFirstExamSolution.Model.SalaryTab>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Vavy\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ModelFirstExamSolution\ModelFirstExamSolution\DataProvider.cs 111 94 ModelFirstExamSolution

Comment: Your entity Sal‌​aryTab does not have Employee property

Comment: http://snag.gy/HjqZd.jpg it does. Here is a link to my model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SalaryTabs - is collection. So, you need select one:

```
dbContext.Companies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CompanyID == companyID).SalaryTabs.FirstOrDefault(...condition...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just can't navigate between entities anymore like before. I got the employee entity which i want to remove and the navigation wont let me through. I don't get the option to select the property I want to get to. I tried all day yesterday and it's the same until now.

```
var emp = dbContext.Employees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeID == employeeID);

            dbContext.Companies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CompanyID == companyID).SalaryTabs.Employee.Remove(emp);

            dbContext.SaveChanges();
```